# Clickable autocomplete, like google

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, onclick, jquery-autocomplete

I'm looking for an autocomplete that have no "submit" button, but that when the user click on the autocomplete keyword he would be redirected to another URL, that i will choose

i'm using http://dyve.net/jquery/?autocomplete and i would like to implement in this script, not use any other (because if i type ODE in this one, he shows CODE and also ODESSA)

example:

user type "goo"
then appears GOOGLE for him, when he click on GOOGLE the script send him to www.google.com
(like "Google"=>"http://www.google.com")

it would be great if i could just do with the script i told you guys
i'm not a programmer so i need like, the code itself, i know its too much to ask but i tried everything =\

thank you!

---

the problem at jUI autocomplete is that i want to do this:

if i type "**ODE**"

it would show "C**ODE**" and also "**ODE**SSA"

not only by the start, thats why i'm trying to use your code in that other one

also, when i used Russ's and karim79's code, it didnt work

Answer (score 10):

I implemented something like that, however, my implementation makes use of [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete).

I use a simple trick, whereby the data returned from the server is a set of strings separated by a newline character "\n", on each line there is a string with the format **suggestion::url**. On the client, I simply split at the separator (I use **::**) and extract the suggestion from the first offset of the resulting array, and the URL from the second. Example:

```
    $("#search").autocomplete("/some/page", {
        selectFirst: false,
        formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
            //make the suggestion look nice
            return "<font color='#3399CC'>" + value.split("::")[0] + "</font>";
        },
        formatResult: function(data,value) {
            //only show the suggestions and not the URLs in the list
            return value.split("::")[0];
        }
    }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        //redirect to the URL in the string
        var pieces = formatted.split("::");
        window.location.href = pieces[1];
    });
```

To clarify what I mean, suppose you type 'goo'. The server might return:

```
google::www.google.com\ngoodstuff::www.example.com
```

That user will see a list appear with 'google' and 'goodstuff'. Clicking on one of those will execute the `result` method of Autocomplete, where I simply take the URL part of the string and redirect. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you not return JSON and then you can skip the ugly string splitting?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [complete walkthrough on how to build an autocomplete search](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GgJN2CC_2s4C&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=unobtrusive+event+binding+javascript&source=bl&ots=7w2ahV5dLL&sig=ZOsSHgUy2MqSkSIFqrQT8dUuGEQ&hl=en&ei=3JmdSpuZBZTLjAe5jaWeAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=autocomplete&f=false).

Essentially, you need to have an event handler to call

```
window.location.href = "your-url-string.com";
```

upon pressing enter or clicking upon a selection.

**EDIT:**

From the [autocomplete documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete)

> **Search Page Replacement**
>
> An autocomplete plugin can be used to
>   search for a term and redirect to a
>   page associated with a resulting item.
>   The following is one way to achieve
>   the redirect:

```
var data = [ {text:'Link A', url:'/page1'}, {text:'Link B', url: '/page2'} ];
$("...").autocomplete(data, {
  formatItem: function(item) {
    return item.text;
  }
}).result(function(event, item) {
  location.href = item.url; // navigate to the chosen URL
});
```

Answer (score 2):

"but even the author dont know how to make this" ??

I think it is easily done by replacing the message-box alert (in the [example page](http://dyve.net/jquery/?autocomplete)) with a call to form.submit(). I haven't tried it, though.

**Edit:**
Here's some example code using http://dyve.net/jquery/?autocomplete:

```
$("#mytextbox").autocomplete("form.php", {onItemSelect:submitTheForm});

function submitTheForm(){ 
     // redirect user to whatever URL
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought; but I'm not that good with js or jQuery. I assumed I was missing something. I'd be interested to know if it solved the problem.

Comment: This would work. The correct url for the jquery-autocomplete project is now http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

the following code works fine for me for turning a search box with data at a remote data source (MySQL database) into a search field AND a redirector if a user selects one of the suggested results:

```
$("#search").autocomplete("search.php", {
    width: 260,
    formatItem: function(data) {
            return data[0];
          }
        }).result(function(event, data) {
     window.location.href = data[1];
});
```

note: I had to make the ajax data separated into two parts:

1. the search term
2. the URL related to that term

eg.

Brad Pitt|/actors/bradpitt

Matt Damon|/actors/mattdamon

jQuery autocomplete automatically separates the data at the pipe (|) and per new line

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery Autocomplete plugin has a matchContains option that will search within the result.  Set it to true and it will return substring matches as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest example you can find at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/KBpXh/)

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 'Google',
        url: 'http://www.google.com'
    },
    {
        value: 'StackOverflow',
        url: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
    }
];

$("input").autocomplete({
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        window.location = ui.item.url;
    }
});
```